# I receive Persitent Collection instead of ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, arraycollection

I want to see if my record in database has related photos or not. But when I call `$car->getCarPhotos()` , I get the instance of `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`, and `var_dump` show the same result for car what has photos, and for car what has no car_photos. Where is my problem? Please , help me.

Comment: Could you include some relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is bothering you? It is supposed to return you collection in both cases. To check whether car has related photos:

```
if ($car->getCarPhotos()->isEmpty()) {
    // Car has no photos
} else {
    // Car has photos
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be a comment but it's terrible for code..

You could add one of a few methods to your model that would be able to tell you if you had any photos attached.

```
/**
 * Check if this car has any attached photos
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function hasPhotos()
{
    return false === $this->carPhotos()->isEmpty();
}
```

Which could be called as `if ($car->hasPhotos())`

```
/**
 * Count how many photos this car has.
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getNbCarPhotos()
{
    return $this->carPhotos()->count();
}
```

Which could be called as `if ($car->getNbPhotos() > 0)` or `if ($car->getNbPhotos() !== 0)`